# STM32 communication between two uc

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2c, communication

How can I utilize the I2C interface between two uc/dev boards to send and receive data and commands?

For example, if the status update request is in uc1, I want it transmitted to uc2.

So I have two ucs (STM32) and I want to establish some type of communication between them using the I2C interface.

Is that possible, and how can I get started?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is that possible? Yes. How do you get started? Depends what you know already, and is too broad a question for this site. Maybe start by studying how to interface a simple I2C peripheral to your board first.

Comment: You would configure one of them as the master and the other as the slave. I2C communication proceeds as normal. You would need to decide how the slave responds to the master - do you want it to loo like a memory device where the master would read/write from/to "addresses" in the slave, or do you want it to look like a register device where the master would read/write from/to registers in the slave? Your decision to make ...

Comment: One is master, one is slave. You get to program both sides. Either bit-banging each side, or using I2C peripherals. If bit-banging, make sure to make the communication slow enough so both sides have time to run the I2C code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  You can get started with a pair of STM32 evaluation boards such as the NUCLEO or Discovery boards (there are dozens of choices).  Then download the STM32Cube software package associated with your evaluation boards.  Then build and run the I2C example project included in the STM32Cube package.  For example, here is a link to the I2C examples for the STM32F4 Discovery board: [https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/tree/master/Projects/STM32F4-Discovery/Examples/I2C](https://github.com/sogongbang/stm32cubef4/tree/master/Projects/STM32F4-Discovery/Examples/I2C)